Computing with Lie algebra of SO(1,3)
Recall the classic presentation of the (complexified) Lie algebra of the Lorentz group:
$$[M^{αβ} , M^{γδ}] = i(η_{γβ} M^{αδ} − η_{αγ} M^{βδ} − η_{βδ} M^{αγ} + η_{αδ} M^{βγ} )$$
Then, define the more physical "rotation" and "boost" generators
$$M^i := \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{ijk} M^{jk} , K^{i} = M^{i0} $$
where $i = 1,2,3$.
After computing the above lie brackets by hand, I'm wondering if there are somehow some more insightful/theory-based ways of showing further identities like
$$[M^i, M^j ] = i \epsilon_{ijk} M^k$$
and
$$[K^i, K^j ] = −i \epsilon_{ijk} M^k$$
Even just approaching these straightforwardly, it seems like it is going to be quite a mess with a three-by-three determinant of kronecker deltas and I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

See also this post.

Used these?
